# Why ASPXAUTH cookie not found in the Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I had spent hours to solve this issue but i can't.

When I work in a Website project, On authenticating a User in login page I redirected the user to the home page using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` it worked and I found the `ASPXAUTH` cookie in the Request.Cookies. But in Web application project I did the same thing but not working. It looks weird. After the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` the page redirected but the `ASPXAUTH` cookie is not found in the `Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]`.

Did I missed anything..?

Why `ASPXAUTH` is not found in the Request.Cookies?

Please kindly help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should inspect the network traffic to see if your cookie is transmitted to the client as part of the redirect. If so, check if everything is ok with this cookie (domain, path, expiration date)

Comment: @jbl thanks for your reply domain,path and expiration date everything is fine. can you please tell how to inspect the network traffic? it would be helpful for me :)

Comment: @jbl I am using Fiddler. In that in header i found the ASPXAUTH cookie in the Set-Cookie header response but in the request i didn't found it. It's getting missed.

Comment: Have you tried on several browsers ? Does your cookie feature port number ? Could there be a requireSSL="true" in your httpCookies or forms element in your web.config ?

Comment: @jbl I tried it in IE, firefox and chrome. It didn't work and in my web.config requireSSL="false".

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The cookie seems to be automatically removed from the Request.Cookies collection as long as it matches the name of FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName.

Comment: @BlueFox I posted an answer how my problem solved. I hope it would be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

we used mojoportal cms for our project, so when I set the FormsAuthentication cookie, the cms also checks for the username in their database. After adding the username in the database the problem solved.

If you are using **https** then check the RequireSSL=true in the Forms Authentication has been used in web.config.

```
<forms name=".mojochangeme"  protection="All" timeout="20160" path="/" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" />
```

I am using two database for my project and if I add the username into another database, that is mojoportal database, then it is not an efficient way for me.

So I used CustomPrincipal class which will be substitute of FormsAuthentication but cookie will not be set.

CustomPrincipal Class:

```
public class CustomPrincipal:IPrincipal
    {
        public IIdentity Identity { get; set; }
        public bool IsInRole(string role) { return false; }
        public CustomPrincipal(string username)
        {
            this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        }
    }
```

For setting the current user in the HttpContext:

```
CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(username);
                    HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
```